# Code with algebraic symbols

Tags: cipher

So my friend asked me to look for what kind of code or cipher (or anything) this is, and I have been researching for a while now without any luck.

The code:

> ++ ×× -- / ×= ×÷ -- -÷  / -= ×÷

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you tell us if this puzzle you made yourself or if it is from someone else? If so, please provide the source!

Comment: My classmate made it, I cannot provide any source tho, neither can she.

Comment: The message is a bit too short and you probably have clues that we haven't. The ending "-= ×÷" might be your classmate's initials. Can you tell us what they are please?

Answer (score 6):

Let's see, then..

There are three lots of two-symbol groups separated by slashes. The number of groups, and the fact that there are two repeats, make it a plausible idea that this is a letter-by-letter substitution cipher of one kind or another.

Working under that assumption, let's transcribe the message:

> abc decf ge

Then, we do the only thing we can: we guess.

The sensible guess is that one of the repeated letters is the most common letter in English: E.

Either option kind of works, the first word could be "the" or "she", and the last word could be "me", all of them allowing for sensible short sentences.

Starting with the first possibility, "THE deEf ge" makes the last word very restricted. The best I can find is the sentence fragment "THE USER IS", but that seems unlikely, since OP's comment seems to indicate this is a note passed in class.

The second option gives "abc dEcf ME", which allows for a very good fit, but only if we assume OP has a three letter nickname ending in L. Looking at the username, "Kyl" might just fit the bill.

Then the message would be

> KYL, HELP ME.

Keeping up the guesswork, we could then try to find some way to map the symbols so that they translate into the guessed letters in some meaningful way, but that isn't always possible. I didn't find any sensible mapping at first glance, and I didn't check all that many guesses either.

That's probably all we can do for now though, since the message is much shorter than 28 letters, which would be the approximate length at which a ciphertext is [likely to have only one plausible plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance), so any certain answer requires that there's a logical way to map the symbols into characters.